# Error converting data type varchar to int using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, database

I have two tables, one for primary key and second for foreign key. When I write the code to insert the data, I get an error.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ImageHotSpotCRUD] 
    @ImaheHSMId int = NULL,
    @ImaheHSName varchar(MAX) = '' ,
    -- @patImage  [varbinary](max)= NULL
    @ImaheHSPath varchar(MAX) = '' ,
    @ImaheHSDId int = NULL,
    @ImaheHSDFKId int = NULL,
    @ImaheHSXCordinate varchar(50) = '',
    @ImaheHSYCordinate varchar(50) = '' ,
    @ImaheHSDisc varchar(MAX) = '' ,
    @IsActive varchar(1) = '' ,
    @Created_by varchar(20) = '' ,
    @CreatedDate datetime ='',
    @ModifyDate datetime ='',
    @ModifyBy varchar(50) = '',
    @Mode varchar(1) =''
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF @Mode = '1'
    BEGIN
        -- Primary key table entry
        DECLARE @ImageNEWPKId int = NULL

        SELECT @ImageNEWPKId = HotSpotID  
        FROM M_ImageHotSpot 
        WHERE ImageName = @ImaheHSName

        IF (@ImageNEWPKId IS NULL)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO M_ImageHotSpot (ImageName, ImagePath, Created_by, Created_date)
            VALUES (@ImaheHSName, @ImaheHSPath, @Created_by, GETDATE()) 

            SELECT @ImageNEWPKId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        END

        -- Foreign key table entry
        DECLARE @ImageNEWDetailPKId int = NULL

        SELECT @ImageNEWDetailPKId = HPDetailID 
        FROM M_ImageHotSpotDetail 
        WHERE HotSpotDescription = @ImaheHSDisc

        IF (@ImageNEWDetailPKId IS NULL)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO M_ImageHotSpotDetail (HotspotIDFK, XCordinate, YCordinate, HotSpotDescription, CreatedByID, CreatedDate)
            VALUES (@ImageNEWPKId, @ImaheHSXCordinate, @ImaheHSYCordinate, @ImaheHSDisc, @Created_by, GETDATE()) 

            -- SELECT @ImaheHSMId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        END
    END
END
```

Here how I pass the data during button click in aspx.cs page:

```
exec ImageHotSpotCRUD 
     @Mode = '1', @ImaheHSName = 'x.jpeg', @ImaheHSPath = 'c:\', 
     @Created_by = 'ADMIN', @ImaheHSXCordinate = '100', @ImaheHSYCordinate = '100', 
     @ImaheHSDisc = 'You Selected Computer'
GO
```

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 18.

**EDIT CODE 1**

```
 public int ImaheHSMId { get; set; }
        public string ImaheHSName { get; set; }
        public string ImaheHSPath { get; set; }

        //Foreign Key Field
        public int ImaheHSDId { get; set; }
        //Foreign Key Id store here
        public int ImaheHSDFKId { get; set; }
        public string ImaheHSXCordinate { get; set; }
        public string ImaheHSYCordinate { get; set; }
        public string ImaheHSDisc { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
```

This are my class property and here is my Table Information. I did every thing perfect but still no data inserted.

**Edit Code 2**
Here is My both the table script.

```
CREATE TABLE [TRIEU].[M_ImageHotSpot](
    [HotSpotID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ImageName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ImagePath] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NULL,
    [Created_by] [nvarchar](18) NULL,
    [Created_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Modified_by] [nvarchar](18) NULL,
    [Modified_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [stats_flag] [char](1) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_M_ImageHotSpot] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [HotSpotID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

```
CREATE TABLE [TRIEU].[M_ImageHotSpotDetail](
    [HPDetailID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [HotspotIDFK] [int] NULL,
    [XCordinate] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [YCordinate] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [HotSpotDescription] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NULL,
    [Created_by] [nvarchar](18) NULL,
    [Created_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Modified_by] [nvarchar](18) NULL,
    [Modified_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [stats_flag] [char](1) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_M_ImageHotSpotDetail] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [HPDetailID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Try to pass "c:\\" instead of "c:\", Double backslash

Comment: Can you add a table script for "M_ImageHotSpotDetail" and "M_ImageHotSpot"?

Comment: @NayanPatel Sir i have update code and add the image of my table.

Comment: I want to SQL script not C#. Can you please give me the SQL table script?

Comment: @NayanPatel sir i just read the wrongly... I have again updated the question inside Edit code 2 you can see the table script. And sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear JParmar,

```
 INSERT INTO M_ImageHotSpotDetail (HotspotIDFK, XCordinate, YCordinate, HotSpotDescription, CreatedByID, CreatedDate)
            VALUES (@ImageNEWPKId, @ImaheHSXCordinate, @ImaheHSYCordinate, @ImaheHSDisc, @Created_by, GETDATE())
```

For the above line, **CreatedByID** and **CreatedDate** column is not exist in M_ImageHotSpotDetail Table.